# Copying data from *.csv into excel

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have a csv file that is filled with outputs from a temperature sensor, it has date, temperature controller address, temp sensor 1 value, temp sensor 2 value, heat power, cool power and limit and alarm states, here is an example with spaces added for readability when opened in notepad:

```
2/10/2016 14:52:26.2, 1, 73.9039, 74.89208, 14.63515, 0, F, None, None, None,
2/10/2016 14:52:36.594, 1, 73.75067, 74.86765, 25.21247, 0, F, None, None, None,
2/10/2016 14:52:47.165, 1, 73.66284, 74.83871, 35.95927, 0, F, None, None, None,
2/10/2016 14:52:57.788, 1, 73.59991, 74.79031, 47.17537, 0, F, None, None, None,
2/10/2016 14:53:8.381, 1, 73.54018, 74.75883, 58.62064, 0, F, None, None, None,
```

however, if I open it in excel, i get this format:

```
52:26.2, 1, 73.9039, 74.89208, 14.63515, 0, F, None, None, None
52:36.6, 1, 73.75067, 74.86765, 25.21247, 0, F, None, None, None
52:47.2, 1, 73.66284, 74.83871, 35.95927, 0, F, None, None, None
52:57.8, 1, 73.59991, 74.79031, 47.17537, 0, F, None, None, None
53:08.4, 1, 73.54018, 74.75883, 58.62064, 0, F, None, None, None
```

I'm trying to use vba in excel to pull the data from this csv file or 
multiple csv files based on user selection through a file picker dialog into a workbook for graphing. The problem I'm running into is that the date and time column doesn't show up correctly. I think it has something to do with the formatting I'm using for the data, but I'm not sure. The format I use is

```
m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss.000
```

For some reason this is the data that shows up in the excel file:

```
1/0/1900 0:52:26.200, 1, 73.90390, 74.89208, 14.64, 0, F, None, None, None
1/0/1900 0:52:36.600, 1, 73.75067, 74.86765, 25.21, 0, F, None, None, None
1/0/1900 0:52:47.200, 1, 73.66284, 74.83871, 35.96, 0, F, None, None, None
1/0/1900 0:52:57.800, 1, 73.59991, 74.79031, 47.18, 0, F, None, None, None
1/0/1900 0:53:08.400, 1, 73.54018, 74.75883, 58.62, 0, F, None, None, None
```

I tried formatting the first column as a number with the format

```
0.0000000000
```

then moving the data, but the column is just blank then because I had to use a range data type to be able to change the format. Here is the code I use to show the file picker and move the data:

```
    Sub fileDialogStart()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                ' Finds the last row in the current workbook
                With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                End With
                ' Imports the data from the selected file
                Call importData(vrtSelectedItem)
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub

Sub importData(ByVal filePath As String)

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim finalRow As Integer
    'Dim targetData as Range

    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    With sourceWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ' Finds the number of rows in the file selected from the file picker
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Stores the first column
        targetData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(finalRow, 1))
    End With

    ' Sets the number format
    'targetData.NumberFormat = "0.0000000000"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ' Puts the new data into the current workbook after the last row of data
        ' in case there is already data in the workbook from a previous import
        .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow + finalRow - 1, 1)) = targetData
    End With

    With sourceWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ' Gets the rest of the data from the file selected
        sourceData = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(finalRow, 10))
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ' Puts the rest of the data into the current workbook
        .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 2), .Cells(lastRow + finalRow - 1, 10)) = sourceData
    End With

    sourceWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    sourceWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

The `fileDialogStart()` sub is called in the sub used to graph at the very beginning and I set the format of the entire first column back to `m/d/yyy h:mm:ss.000` in there after the data is imported. Maybe the problem has something to do with the fact that i'm opening the csv file as a workbook? I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want the date and time in a single cell or in adjacent cells ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent A single cell

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I edited the question to reflect something that I just figured out, the csv file has different formatting if I open it in excel rather than notepad. The notepad format is the correct one

Comment: @Logan - I am curious how the date values come in if you import the csv file through **Data>Get External Data>From Text** in the Ribbon UI (where you can adjust the delimiters).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I just checked and the data comes in the same way as if i just open the file in excel

Comment: @Logan - You need to play with delimiters. Jeeped provided the answer for what I was talking about. (I think the delimiters is the wrong word actually, but the DataType is what I was thinking ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) allows you to specify the [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) of each field. This equates to the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx). Specifying an **xlMDYFormat** format for the first field is sufficient to bring the datetimes in correctly (including their fractions of seconds).

```
Sub openCSV()
    Dim fp As String, fn As String, wbCSV As Workbook

    fp = Environ("TMP")
    fn = "datetemp.csv"
    Debug.Print fp & Chr(92) & fn
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fp & Chr(92) & fn, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Space:=False, _
                       Other:=False, Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlMDYFormat), _
                       Local:=True
    With ActiveWorkbook
        With Worksheets(1)
            With .Columns(1)
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ss.000"
                .AutoFit
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The **Local:=True** may not be desired depending upon your own regional settings. It worked fine for my EN-US defaults.

Comment: Double-clicking a CSV out of an Explorer folder window is just simply **not** a reliable method of getting the data into a worksheet. Data ► Get External Data ► From Text is another that uses a [QueryTables.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx) method with the same options for the **FieldInfo** parameters but I find that the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) to be best suited for my purposes.

Comment: This works perfectly! The only thing is that I still am not getting the fractions of seconds on the end, they're showing up as all 0's, I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to get the milliseconds, I changed `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"` to `.NumberFormat = "0.0000000000"` and then changed it back to the date and time after it was imported. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Excel is doing some weird things; however when I run this:

```
Sub WTF()
   Dim FilesToOpen
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Dim ary, bry, DQ As String
   DQ = Chr(34)

   FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Text Files to Open")

   Close #1
   Open FilesToOpen For Input As #1

   j = 1
   Do While Not EOF(1)
      Line Input #1, TextLine
      ary = Split(TextLine, ",")
      bry = Split(ary(0), " ")
         Cells(j, 1).Formula = "=datevalue(" & DQ & bry(0) & DQ & ")+timevalue(" & DQ & bry(1) & DQ & ")"
         Cells(j, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"
         For k = 2 To 10
            Cells(j, k) = ary(k - 1)
         Next k
      j = j + 1
   Loop

   Close #1
End Sub
```

On your posted data,  I get:

[image]

What I cannot explain is why Excel does such a poor job of opening the file directly.

**Perhaps some one else can explain this.**